# Is there a cleaner way to achieve this XML to JSON transformation of NHS data

Tags: php, json, xml, foreach

I am consuming location and address data from a public NHS API, it is coming in in an XML format and I have transformed it to JSON for use within my webapp.

My code is working and producing the desired result, however I cannot help but cringe at the amount of nested foreach loops inside this code.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result that will be more performant?

I have tried using simplexml_load_string and many variations and it refuses to output/parse the content of a nested  element containing s:organisationSummary data.

Here is the PHP class

```
class XmlElement {
    public $name;
    public $attributes;
    public $content;
    public $children;
}

class GpService
{
    protected $apiKey;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiKey = env('NHS_API_KEY');
    }

    public function xmlToObject($xml) {
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
        xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $tags);
        xml_parser_free($parser);

        $elements = array();  // the currently filling [child] XmlElement array
        $stack = array();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
          $index = count($elements);
          if ($tag['type'] == "complete" || $tag['type'] == "open") {
            $elements[$index] = new XmlElement;
            $elements[$index]->name = $tag['tag'];
            $elements[$index]->attributes = (isset($tag['attributes']))?$tag['attributes']:null;
            $elements[$index]->content = (isset($tag['value']))?$tag['value']:null;
            if ($tag['type'] == "open") {  // push
              $elements[$index]->children = array();
              $stack[count($stack)] = &$elements;
              $elements = &$elements[$index]->children;
            }
          }
          if ($tag['type'] == "close") {  // pop
            $elements = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
            unset($stack[count($stack) - 1]);
          }
        }
        return $elements[0];  // the single top-level element
    }

    public function searchByPostcode($postcode)
    {
        $postcodeRequest = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $postcodeGet = $postcodeRequest->request('GET', 'https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/' . $postcode . '/?distance=15', [
            'headers' => [
                'subscription-key' => $this->apiKey,
            ]
        ]);

        //Convert the XML string into an SimpleXMLElement object.
        $xmlObject = $this->xmlToObject($postcodeGet->getBody());
        $outputObject = [];

        // Absolutely insane loops to get data into the format I would like
        foreach($xmlObject->children as $key => $entry)
        {
            if($entry->name === 'entry')
            {
                foreach($entry->children as $value)
                {
                    if($value->name === 'content')
                    {
                        foreach($value->children as $objectProperty)
                        {
                            foreach($objectProperty->children as $dataItem)
                            {
                                if(is_array($dataItem->children))
                                {
                                    foreach($dataItem->children as $childKey => $childDataItem)
                                    {
                                        if($childDataItem->name == 's:addressLine')
                                        {
                                            $childDataItem->name = $childDataItem->name . $childKey;
                                        }
                                        $outputObject[$key][str_replace('s:','',strtolower($childDataItem->name))] = $childDataItem->content;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $outputObject[$key][str_replace('s:','',strtolower($dataItem->name))] = $dataItem->content;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $outputObject;
    }
}
```

Here is the XML Data:

```
<feed xmlns:s="https://api.nhs.uk/data/services" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">NHS website - GP Practices Near Postcode - LE2 1DA - Within 15km</title>
  <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/le21da?range=15</id>
  <rights type="text">© Crown Copyright 2009</rights>
  <updated>2019-08-22T15:04:20+01:00</updated>
  <category term="Search"/>
  <logo>https://www.nhs.uk/nhscwebservices/documents/logo1.jpg</logo>
  <author>
    <name>NHS website</name>
    <uri>https://www.nhs.uk</uri>
    <email>webservices@nhschoices.nhs.uk</email>
  </author>
  <link rel="self" type="application/xml" title="NHS website - GP Practices Near Postcode - LE2 1DA - Within 15km" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/LE21DA&amp;range=15"/>
  <link rel="first" type="application/xml" title="first" length="1000" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/LE21DA&amp;range=15&amp;page=1"/>
  <link rel="next" type="application/xml" title="next" length="1000" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/LE21DA&amp;range=15&amp;page=2"/>
  <link rel="last" type="application/xml" title="last" length="1000" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/postcode/LE21DA&amp;range=15&amp;page=10"/>
  <tracking xmlns="https://api.nhs.uk/data/services">&lt;img style="border: 0; width: 1px; height: 1px;" alt="" src="https://statse.webtrendslive.com/dcs2221tai1ckz5huxw0mfq86_1m2w/njs.gif?dcsuri=/organisations%2fgppractices%2fpostcode%2fLE21DA&amp;amp;wt.cg_s=OrganisationData&amp;amp;wt.cg_n=syndication&amp;synduserid=7a6ea2a0-8dec-11e9-8e02-f5191ebd3281&amp;syndreviewdate=22-08-2019T14:04&amp;synduserid=7a6ea2a0-8dec-11e9-8e02-f5191ebd3281&amp;syndreviewdate=22-08-2019T14:04"/&gt;</tracking>
  <s:SearchCoords>52.6299,-1.11502</s:SearchCoords>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4863</id>
    <title type="text">Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4863"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=42231"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82116</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>25 Severn Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0NN</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162543253</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11859357357025</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6293983459473</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.247038430918239</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4901</id>
    <title type="text">Dr R Kapur &amp; Partners</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Dr R Kapur &amp; Partners" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4901"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Dr R Kapur &amp; Partners" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=36753"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Dr R Kapur &amp; Partners</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82659</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>St Peters Health Centre</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Sparkenhoe Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0TA</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162951258</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11907768249512</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6310386657715</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.30219913005026</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4827</id>
    <title type="text">Shefa Medical Practice</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Shefa Medical Practice" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4827"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Shefa Medical Practice" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=38960"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Shefa Medical Practice</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82080</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>St Peters Health Centre</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Sparkenhoe Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0TA</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162957835</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11907768249512</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6310386657715</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.30219913005026</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4902</id>
    <title type="text">St Peter's Health Centre - Mansingh &amp; Partner</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="St Peter's Health Centre - Mansingh &amp; Partner" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4902"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="St Peter's Health Centre - Mansingh &amp; Partner" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=35950"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>St Peter's Health Centre - Mansingh &amp; Partner</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82660</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>Sparkenhoe Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0TA</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162957827</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11907768249512</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6310386657715</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.30219913005026</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4848</id>
    <title type="text">Al-Waqas Medical Centre</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Al-Waqas Medical Centre" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4848"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Al-Waqas Medical Centre" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=43636"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Al-Waqas Medical Centre</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82099</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>AL-Waqas Medical Practice</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>91 St Peters Road</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 1DJ</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162543003</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.10840618610382</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6290435791016</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.458084198394662</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4889</id>
    <title type="text">Community Health Centre</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Community Health Centre" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4889"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Community Health Centre" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=42802"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Community Health Centre</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82643</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>Melbourne Centre</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Melbourne Road</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0GU</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162622946</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11336529254913</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.6338653564453</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.462480666213577</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4801</id>
    <title type="text">Sayeed Medical Centre</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Sayeed Medical Centre" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4801"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Sayeed Medical Centre" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=42819"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Sayeed Medical Centre</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82060</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>352-354 East Park Road</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE5 5AY</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01163232030</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.10658276081085</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.630802154541</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.581034496166074</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4759</id>
    <title type="text">Melbourne Street Surgery</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Melbourne Street Surgery" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4759"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Melbourne Street Surgery" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=36620"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Melbourne Street Surgery</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82031</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>56 Melbourne Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 0AS</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162536299</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.11437559127808</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.636344909668</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.717122615984056</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4770</id>
    <title type="text">East Park Medical Centre - R P Pandya</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="East Park Medical Centre - R P Pandya" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4770"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="East Park Medical Centre - R P Pandya" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=40574"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>East Park Medical Centre - R P Pandya</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82037</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>264-266 East Park Road</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE5 5FD</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>01162736330</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.10444343090057</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.633544921875</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.822717143851754</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4834</id>
    <title type="text">Evington Medical Centre</title>
    <updated>2019-08-22T14:04:20Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Evington Medical Centre" href="https://api.nhs.uk/data/gppractices/4834"/>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Evington Medical Centre" href="https://www.nhs.uk/Services/GP/Overview/DefaultView.aspx?id=36363"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <s:organisationSummary>
        <s:name>Evington Medical Centre</s:name>
        <s:odsCode>C82088</s:odsCode>
        <s:address>
          <s:addressLine>2 - 6 Halsbury Street</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicester</s:addressLine>
          <s:addressLine>Leicestershire</s:addressLine>
          <s:postcode>LE2 1QA</s:postcode>
        </s:address>
        <s:contact type="General">
          <s:telephone>0116 3190343</s:telephone>
        </s:contact>
        <s:geographicCoordinates>
          <s:longitude>-1.10676002502441</s:longitude>
          <s:latitude>52.624267578125</s:latitude>
        </s:geographicCoordinates>
        <s:Distance>0.834829502560211</s:Distance>
      </s:organisationSummary>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "13":{
         "name":"Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)",
         "odscode":"C82116",
         "addressline0":"25 Severn Street",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0NN",
         "telephone":"01162543253",
         "longitude":"-1.11859357357025",
         "latitude":"52.6293983459473",
         "distance":"0.247038430918239"
      },
      "14":{
         "name":"Dr R Kapur & Partners",
         "odscode":"C82659",
         "addressline0":"St Peters Health Centre",
         "addressline1":"Sparkenhoe Street",
         "addressline2":"Leicester",
         "addressline3":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0TA",
         "telephone":"01162951258",
         "longitude":"-1.11907768249512",
         "latitude":"52.6310386657715",
         "distance":"0.30219913005026"
      },
      "15":{
         "name":"Shefa Medical Practice",
         "odscode":"C82080",
         "addressline0":"St Peters Health Centre",
         "addressline1":"Sparkenhoe Street",
         "addressline2":"Leicester",
         "addressline3":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0TA",
         "telephone":"01162957835",
         "longitude":"-1.11907768249512",
         "latitude":"52.6310386657715",
         "distance":"0.30219913005026"
      },
      "16":{
         "name":"St Peter's Health Centre - Mansingh & Partner",
         "odscode":"C82660",
         "addressline0":"Sparkenhoe Street",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0TA",
         "telephone":"01162957827",
         "longitude":"-1.11907768249512",
         "latitude":"52.6310386657715",
         "distance":"0.30219913005026"
      },
      "17":{
         "name":"Al-Waqas Medical Centre",
         "odscode":"C82099",
         "addressline0":"AL-Waqas Medical Practice",
         "addressline1":"91 St Peters Road",
         "addressline2":"Leicester",
         "addressline3":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 1DJ",
         "telephone":"01162543003",
         "longitude":"-1.10840618610382",
         "latitude":"52.6290435791016",
         "distance":"0.458084198394662"
      },
      "18":{
         "name":"Community Health Centre",
         "odscode":"C82643",
         "addressline0":"Melbourne Centre",
         "addressline1":"Melbourne Road",
         "addressline2":"Leicester",
         "addressline3":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0GU",
         "telephone":"01162622946",
         "longitude":"-1.11336529254913",
         "latitude":"52.6338653564453",
         "distance":"0.462480666213577"
      },
      "19":{
         "name":"Sayeed Medical Centre",
         "odscode":"C82060",
         "addressline0":"352-354 East Park Road",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE5 5AY",
         "telephone":"01163232030",
         "longitude":"-1.10658276081085",
         "latitude":"52.630802154541",
         "distance":"0.581034496166074"
      },
      "20":{
         "name":"Melbourne Street Surgery",
         "odscode":"C82031",
         "addressline0":"56 Melbourne Street",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 0AS",
         "telephone":"01162536299",
         "longitude":"-1.11437559127808",
         "latitude":"52.636344909668",
         "distance":"0.717122615984056"
      },
      "21":{
         "name":"East Park Medical Centre - R P Pandya",
         "odscode":"C82037",
         "addressline0":"264-266 East Park Road",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE5 5FD",
         "telephone":"01162736330",
         "longitude":"-1.10444343090057",
         "latitude":"52.633544921875",
         "distance":"0.822717143851754"
      },
      "22":{
         "name":"Evington Medical Centre",
         "odscode":"C82088",
         "addressline0":"2 - 6 Halsbury Street",
         "addressline1":"Leicester",
         "addressline2":"Leicestershire",
         "postcode":"LE2 1QA",
         "telephone":"0116 3190343",
         "longitude":"-1.10676002502441",
         "latitude":"52.624267578125",
         "distance":"0.834829502560211"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use a different XML parser. I wrote this, which people seem to like: https://github.com/sabre-io/xml

Comment: @Evert Thanks I'll take a look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use proper methods to traverse the XML document, rather than looking at every single element and checking its name.

Your two best options are DOM methods and XPath. The former will be familiar to you if you've worked with front-end JavaScript code (e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.getElementById`.) The latter has a steeper learning curve but is far more powerful. (XSLT is also a good option for transforming XML, but I'm not very familiar with it.)

Step one though, is to use the proper XML library. The XML functions you're using are *very* low level. I'd recommend using PHP's `DomDocument` extension instead. Let's dive in!

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("nhs.xml");
// assume XML document is stored in a variable called $xml
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
// thankfully we can ignore namespaces!
$summaries = $dom->getElementsByTagName("organisationSummary");
// go through each <organisationSummary> element
foreach ($summaries as $os) {
    $entry_data = [
        // note we're using $os and not $dom now, so we get child elements of this particular element
        "name"         => $os->getElementsByTagName("name")[0]->textContent,
        "odscode"      => $os->getElementsByTagName("odsCode")[0]->textContent,
        "addressline0" => $os->getElementsByTagName("addressLine")[0]->textContent,
        // provide a default empty string in case there's no further lines
        "addressline1" => $os->getElementsByTagName("addressLine")[1]->textContent ?? "",
        "addressline2" => $os->getElementsByTagName("addressLine")[2]->textContent ?? "",
        "addressline3" => $os->getElementsByTagName("addressLine")[3]->textContent ?? "",
        "postcode"     => $os->getElementsByTagName("postcode")[0]->textContent,
        "telephone"    => $os->getElementsByTagName("telephone")[0]->textContent,
        "longitude"    => $os->getElementsByTagName("longitude")[0]->textContent,
        "latitude"     => $os->getElementsByTagName("latitude")[0]->textContent,
        "distance"     => $os->getElementsByTagName("Distance")[0]->textContent,
    ];
    $json_data[] = $entry_data;
}
if (count($json_data)) {
    $output = ["success" => true, "data" => $json_data];
} else {
    $output = ["success" => false];
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM and XPath expressions. All the data is inside the `{https://api.nhs.uk/data/services}organisationSummary` nodes.

The following example register the prefix `service` for the namespace `https://api.nhs.uk/data/services` (That is what the `s` in your example resolves to). Then it fetches any `{https://api.nhs.uk/data/services}organisationSummary` node using the `//service:organisationSummary` expression.

For each each organisation it builds up an `$item` variable using expressions for scalar values. A loop is used for the `{https://api.nhs.uk/data/services}addressLine` nodes.

```
// create the DOM document and load the XML 
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
// create an Xpath instance for the document - register namespace
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('service', 'https://api.nhs.uk/data/services');
$json = [
  "success" => true,
  // force object for data - it will be an array otherwise
  "data" => new stdClass()
];

// iterate over all organisationSummary nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//service:organisationSummary') as $index => $organisation) {
  // fetch single values
  $item = [
    "name" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:name)', $organisation),
    "odscode" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:odsCode)', $organisation),
    "postcode" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:address/service:postcode)', $organisation),
    "telephone" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:contact/service:telephone)', $organisation),
    "longitude" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:geographicCoordinates/service:longitude)', $organisation),
    "latitude" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:geographicCoordinates/service:latitude)', $organisation),
    "distance" => $xpath->evaluate('string(service:Distance)', $organisation)
  ];
  // add the addressLine values
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('service:address/service:addressLine', $organisation) as $lineIndex => $line) {
    $item['addressline'.$lineIndex] = $line->textContent;
  }
  // add the $item
  $json['data']->{$index} = $item;
}

echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "name": "Highfields Surgery (R Wadhwa)",
            "odscode": "C82116",
            "postcode": "LE2 0NN",
            "telephone": "01162543253",
            "longitude": "-1.11859357357025",
            "latitude": "52.6293983459473",
            "distance": "0.247038430918239",
            "addressline0": "25 Severn Street",
            "addressline1": "Leicester",
            "addressline2": "Leicestershire"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Dr R Kapur & Partners",
            "odscode": "C82659",
            "postcode": "LE2 0TA",
            "telephone": "01162951258",
            "longitude": "-1.11907768249512",
            "latitude": "52.6310386657715",
            "distance": "0.30219913005026",
            "addressline0": "St Peters Health Centre",
            "addressline1": "Sparkenhoe Street",
            "addressline2": "Leicester",
            "addressline3": "Leicestershire"
        },
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much will do a bit more reading around xpath as I havent really tried it for this